# Why the following function is not tail recursive?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

The following function seems to me as tail recursive
But the compiler still complains if I put a `@tailrec` above it:

```
def loop(newInterests: Set[Interest], oldInterests: Set[Interest]): Set[Interest] = {
  newInterests.headOption.fold(oldInterests){ ni =>
    val withSameKeyWord = oldInterests.find(oi => oi.keyword == ni.keyword)

    withSameKeyWord.fold(loop(newInterests.tail, oldInterests + ni)){ k => 
      loop(newInterests.tail,
      oldInterests - k + k.copy(count = k.count + 1))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not returning the result involving `loop`, but the result of `fold`s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated by thefourtheye, your function returns the results of `fold`s. A tail recursive version (with pattern matching) would look something like:

```
@tailrec
def loop(newInterests: Set[Interest], oldInterests: Set[Interest]): Set[Interest] = {
  newInterests.headOption match {
    case None => oldInterests
    case Some(ni) =>
      oldInterests.find(oi => oi.keyword == ni.keyword) match {
        case None => loop(newInterests.tail, oldInterests + ni)
        case Some(k) => loop(newInterests.tail, oldInterests - k + k.copy(count = k.count + 1))
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.